# Pyspark Zeppelin - Fail to open PythonInterpreter

Tags: java, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I am new to Zeppelin and Pyspark.

I have tried in vain to get Zeppelin to run with Pyspark.

My setup:

- 4 x Raspberry 4(8GB)
- Ubuntu Server 64bit 20.04
- Hadoop: 3.2.2
- Yarn
- Spark 3.1.1 & Hadoop integrated
- Zeppelin 0.9

Pi01 as Master Pi02-04 as Worker. Spark installed on all Pi.

Hadoop & Yarn are running without any problems.
Pyspark shell runs and I can execute commands.
[image]

But same command in zeppelin fails..

[image]

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory

However, with Zeppelin %Pyspark as well as %python does not work. I have now searched for many hours but have not found a solution (switching from Debian to Ubuntu and back again).

[image]

I also tried to access the Spark Master from my Win10 PC with Jupyter Notebook but I don't know how to do that and finally gave up.

Any Ideas?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I got it working.  I used Spark version 2.4.7 and now it works. I don't know if this is a coincidence or if it was really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding PYTHON installation path to Zeppelin config

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32960752)